# ExtJs4.1.1 pagingToolBar not worked on Firefox

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagination, extjs4.1

ExtJs pagination code not work properly on **Firefox**, It works proper on other browser like IE10,Chrome etc.

I have worked with ExtJs 4.1.1.
and on that part I defined a pagination toolbar for comboGrid and according to that my pagination worked.
I coded something like this :

```
var bar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
    store: Store,
    displayInfo: true,
    itemid:'paginationToolbar',
    items: [
    '-',
    'Per Page: ',
    combo],         
    displayMsg: 'Display {0} - {1} of {2}',
    emptyMsg: "No display",
    handleRefresh: Ext.emptyFn,
    doRefresh: function() {
        // Logic
    }
});
```

and apply this bar on Ext.apply method.

Comment: Please [make a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) that is working in other browsers but not in Firefox. I will look into the issue once your fiddle is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Dump your data to a `JSON` on the page's body, use this [jQuery's plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) instead.

See the `loading data (JSON)` and `Pivot Grid` Examples.

Comment: If you're working with ExtJS to build grids and the like with pagination, this wouldn't be a  very wise choice imo.

Comment: @hbulens that is your opinion, If you are working in the tech industry, you would know that it is more practical to write hybrids that works well, other than being a purist that takes 4 weeks to look for a grid solution ;)  Oh, and jqGrid has same look&feel as extjs, and everyone loads some jQuery eventually to the page, so there are no real reasons why you should not do it. now.

Answer (score 0):

I have written something about this on my [blog](https://hendrikbulens.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/extjs-grid-page-size-letting-the-user-decide/), had a similar problem recently. The code below works on ExtJS 4 (can't recall the version) and it definitely works ExtJS 6.0.0 and ExtJS 6.0.1. I'd be surprised the reason would be version number, as the original blog post I based myself on dates from a few years back - so it should work any version you pick.

```
Ext.define('Ext.toolbar.PagingComboToolbar', {
extend: 'Ext.PagingToolbar',
displayInfo: true,
pageSize: 50,  
displayMsg: 'Display {0} - {1} of {2}',
emptyMsg: "No display",
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    this.store.pageSize = this.pageSize;
    var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        name: 'perpage',
        width: 75,
        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: ['id'],
            data: [
              ['10'],
              ['20'],
              ['50'],
              ['75'],
              ['100'],
              ['150']
            ]
        }),
        value: this.pageSize,
        listWidth: 70,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        displayField: 'id',
        valueField: 'id',
        editable: false,
        forceSelection: true,
        listeners: {
            select: {
                fn: function (combo, record) {
                    var newPagesize = parseInt(record.get('id'), 10);
                    this.pageSize = newPagesize;
                    this.store.pageSize = newPagesize;
                    this.store.loadPage(this.store.currentPage);
               },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: [
            'Per page: ', 
            combo
        ]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

You then call it like this:

```
var bar = new Ext.toolbar.PagingComboToolbar({
store: Store,     
handleRefresh: Ext.emptyFn,
doRefresh: function() {
    // Logic
}
});
```

Naturally, if your combobox behaves a little bit differently, you can replace it. Or you can extend the entire class so it's able to accept comoboxes in the constructor for instance.